# Pass CDN domain name to origin server

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, cdn

I was wondering if Amazon Cloudfront can pass to the origin server the CDN domain name the request is coming from. Let me explain.

- I have an external LAMP server, associated to an origin domain (e.g., origin.mydomain.com)
- I've successfully set up Cloudfront, setting origin.mydomain.com as origin server
- Finally, I pointed 2 different (CDN) domains to Cloudfront (e.g., [www.firstdomain.com](http://www.firstdomain.com) and [www.seconddomain.com](http://www.seconddomain.com))

Now, all this setup is working perfectly.

But there is 1 information I'm missing: when the origin server (origin.mydomain.com) receives a request, I haven't found a way to know if the request originally comes from [www.firstdomain.com](http://www.firstdomain.com) or www.seconddomain.com; cloudfront sends to the origin server all information about the request, except the original CDN domain - or if it does, I don't know how/where to get it.

So, resuming, I have this:

DNS domain(s) -> Cloudfront -> Origin domain -> LAMP Server

The question is: How can LAMP get the DNS domain name the request is originally coming from?

Do I miss any cloudfront setting, or there is some trick I can use to get that info?

Note: I know I can create several properties pointing to the same origin server, but that is not a viable solution for this project.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use the logging in Cloudfront, because the only time that Cloudfront actually makes requests to your server is when they do not have a cached version of that particular file.

To turn on logging you need to log into the AWS Console and choose Edit in the Distribution Details for the distribution you want to enable access logs to be delivered. Then you set the target bucket and prefix for AWS to deliver log files to. The logging target should be another S3 bucket than the origin. Otherwise your report will include requests for log files delivered by Amazon and download requests for log files.

When you configure logging it will save logs in the bucket you specified in this format: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/AccessLogs.html#LogFileFormat